# Stop the PivotControl allowing swipe

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivot

So I'm trying to make a "tabbed web browser" for Windows Phone 8. I can't seem to work out quite how I'm to do this bit. I've made all the tab control stuff using a PivotControl (it replaced TabControl in Windows 8 I believe). I can add & remove tabs dynamically, and I think that system is pretty good. Unfortunately, I can't work out how to stop the swipe gesture from changing tabs. I want the user to have to swipe only on the Pivot Controls header, not on the contents... I'm putting the website itself in the contents so it doesn't allow the user to scroll when zoomed into the website, as the gesture is overridden by the phones desire to switch Pivot item...

How would I go about preventing the pivot from switching when the user swipes inside of the WebBrowser control?